# Get Previous text in place of null cell in a field in Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.1, postgresql-9.3

Please i want to replace null text with the previous text that is NOT null in postgresql

I want to use the previous text whenever its null

[image: Sample of table]

Comment: What do you mean by previous?

Comment: Your request is not really clear ... please give us a table sample, and result you would like to get. Thanks.

Comment: Add example data and better describe your question.  For instance, are you updating a table or altering a select statement?  If it's a query, add the query.  If it's a table, add the table definition.

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

It can be achieve by using function in PostgreSQL and using for loop.

```
declare

r record;
previous_country    text;
current_country text;

begin

for r in
    select date, id, country from country_detail

loop
    if not r.country is null then
        previous_country = r.country
        current_country = r.country
    else
        current_country = previous_country

    return query
    select
        r.date,
        r.id,
        current_country

end loop;
```

I hope it works for you.